# Can access ActiveRecord object, but not its attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm rendering a view in Rails using `form_for` and `nested_form_fields`. Here, `@procedure_step` is a record that `has_many :procedure_step_actions`, each of which `belongs_to :error`, which is a `ProcedureError` that has (among some relations to other models) an integer `:code` that I'm trying to access and print out to the page. Here's my template:

```
<%= form_for @procedure_step do |f| %>
    <%= f.nested_fields_for :procedure_step_actions do |act| %>
        <%= act.object.error.code %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I run this, I get `undefined method 'code' for nil:NilClass`. Okay, so my relations are messed up and I can't access `act.object.error`, right? Changing my template to display that instead yields `#<ProcedureError:0x0000000ece02a8>`, which is what one would expect of a functioning relation. Dumping its contents to the screen using `debug` shows all the attributes of the record, including `code`, but I still can't access it with the original template! Clearly `act.object.error` is not `nil`, so Rails telling me that `act.object.error` is `nil` doesn't make any sense to me.

Frustrated, I tried to work around the problem by using `act.object.error.to_json`. This printed the correct JSON for the record with all its attributes. Using `JSON.load()` on this gave me a correct `Hash` of all the attributes, but using `[:code]` to try to access the code gives me `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`. Again, I know that object isn't `nil`, but Rails still refuses to allow me to access it.

Running out of ideas, I tried to use regular expressions to pull the code out of the raw JSON string. `/"code":([0-9]+)/.match(act.object.error.to_json)` returned `#<MatchData "\"code\":69" 1:"69">`, which is right. I used `[1]` to try to access the code number that was matched, but again I got `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

Enough with ActiveRecord, I thought to myself. I decided to turn to raw SQL queries. I got the ID of the error in question using `act.object.error_id`, then printed that to the screen first to make sure I could access it. Luckily, I could. Then I inserted it into my SQL query with `"... WHERE id = #{act.object.error_id}"`. I refreshed the page again and was greeted with a SQL error. It showed the final SQL query string I had generated, but it ended with `WHERE id =`. The ID of the error didn't get added to the string. `ProcedureError.find(action.object.error_id)` gave a similar error.

I'm totally out of ideas. What could possibly be preventing me from accessing one simple integer in so many different ways?

Comment: So, just to be clear, your ProcedureStepAction has `belongs_to :error, class_name: 'ProcedureError', foreign_key: :error_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I can see right off the bat is you are violating Law of Demeter here

```
act.object.error.code
```

The form object obviously has to stay but you can delegate access to the subobjects by making a method on the `procedure_step` which can help with handling nulls, and other error cases.

Try delegating that first as I'm not sure if the scope that is created by nested_forms_for will allow the ActiveRecord::Relation object to perform properly. I'll double check locally.

A delegation might look like the following

```
class ProcedureStepActions
   belongs_to :error
   def error_code
       @error.code
   end
end
```

EDIT:

Other things that might be helpful are the version of Ruby and Rails you are using and any other additional gems or libraries.

Comment: I added a method to ProcedureStepAction that pulls the error and returns its code, but it had the same nil object problem that I was getting originally. I'm using Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.2.3, and nested_form_fields 0.7.6 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: 'k well I repro'd a similar issue on my machine (Rails 3.2, Ruby 2.2.0 and Mac) and it looks like some other similar issues have been reported to the owner of that project - https://github.com/ncri/nested_form_fields/issues/55 I'm assuming this is either a bug in that lib or in Rails

Comment: My guess is the former. I think this kind of spaghetti access isn't really recommended for complex models AFAIK too. You might want to just make ProcedureErrors inherit from ProcedureStepActions and creating a cusom workflow for errors

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a couple of issues here. The first is that you probably want to be using [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for), rather than `nested_fields_for`, if you're using 4.x.

The second is similar to what the first answer has indicated. You have a nested fields form, which allows you to nest one level in, but you are trying to nest two levels in. By addressing your law of demeter violation you should be able to make some more progress.

Debugging things like this you can get more information by throwing in a [binding.pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) or [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) right in your erb.

```
<%- binding.pry %>
```

Then reload the page. Your server will be stopped at that point in your code and you can play with variable values to learn more about what's going on.